# nodejs bodybarser for value objects from formdata

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a bodyparser that parses the entire incomming request form data object?

I have a key value which has to be an object. Unfortunately the body parser from express doesn't parse it. It only parses the first level objects.

```
KEY: emails
VALUE: [ {name: "jogo@yahoo.com", activated:false}, {...}]
```

What the express body parser does is returning the key emails as string

```
typeof(emails) >> string
```

I'd have to parse each key value pair, which is very uncomfortable. I'm testing the

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior before.  Is it possible that the front-end is sending you the value as a string?  This would be fixing the issue at the source, instead of adding another middleware to parse the JSON again.

Comment: How about this, didn't try it out yet: bodyParser.json({type:multipart/formdata}) ? I built up the rest-Service to be capable of receiving values as object. Undoing it would be a lot of work. I further implemented a json Schema Validation, this has to be refractored as well .... too much work :(

Comment: ah, I don't think you should be using the json bodyParser if you're expecting form data.  Try using `bodyParser.urlencoded(options)` and let me know!

Comment: It worked with raw data and data_type application/json. The url encoding didn't work either.